# How to add Gaussian noise with varying std during training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am training a CNN using keras and tensorflow. I would like to add Gaussian noise to my input data during training and reduce the percentage of the noise in further steps. What I do right now, I use:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Input, GaussianNoise, BatchNormalization
inputs = Input(shape=x_train_n.shape[1:])
bn0 = BatchNormalization(axis=1, scale=True)(inputs)
g0 = GaussianNoise(0.5)(bn0)
```

The variable that GaussianNoise takes is the standard deviation of the noise distribution and I couldn't assign a dynamic value to it, how can I add for example a noise, and then decrease this value based on the epoch that I am in?

Comment: Thanks for your response I’ve already voted up, how to modify the std was helpful. But still I’m hoping to get an answer how to use noise percentage instead of using std.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply design a custom `callback` which changes the `stddev` before training for a epoch.

Reference:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GaussianNoise

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_callback

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Add, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random


from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Input, GaussianNoise, BatchNormalization
inputs = Input(shape=100)
bn0 = BatchNormalization(axis=1, scale=True)(inputs)
g0 = GaussianNoise(0.5)(bn0) 
d0 = Dense(10)(g0)
model = Model(inputs, d0)

model.compile('adam', 'mse')
model.summary()


class MyCustomCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):

  def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
    self.model.layers[2].stddev = random.uniform(0, 1)
    print('updating sttdev in training')
    print(self.model.layers[2].stddev)


X_train = np.zeros((10,100))
y_train = np.zeros((10,10))

noise_change = MyCustomCallback()
model.fit(X_train, 
          y_train, 
          batch_size=32, 
          epochs=5, 
          callbacks = [noise_change])
```

```
Model: "model_5"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_6 (InputLayer)         [(None, 100)]             0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_5 (Batch (None, 100)               400       
_________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_5 (GaussianNo (None, 100)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 10)                1010      
=================================================================
Total params: 1,410
Trainable params: 1,210
Non-trainable params: 200
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/5
updating sttdev in training
0.984045691131548
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.6031
Epoch 2/5
updating sttdev in training
0.02821459469022025
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 742us/step - loss: 1.5966
Epoch 3/5
updating sttdev in training
0.6102984511769268
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.8818
Epoch 4/5
updating sttdev in training
0.021155188690323512
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.2032
Epoch 5/5
updating sttdev in training
0.35950227285165115
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.8817

<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fc67ce9e668>
```

Comment: Good solution (+1). However, since the OP is interested to change the value of `stddev` **at the start of each epoch**, it's better to modify your solution and use `on_epoch_begin` method of `Callback` instead (currently, your solution apply the change at the start of each batch; this may confuse the reader). Further, please remove all the other redundant methods (like `on_test_batch_begin`, etc.) to make it more concise and clear.

Comment: note at least in tf1 this wont work. you need to use K.variable