# How to add different noise percentage to data during training based on SNR of the input signal in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am training a CNN using tensorflow and keras, I would like to add 10%-5% Gaussian noise based on my SNR to my data during training.

Right now I use `GaussianNoise` layer to add noise but the only parameter to vary here is the std. (based on [How to add Gaussian noise with varying std during training?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61466507/how-to-add-gaussian-noise-with-varying-std-during-training/61467929#61467929))

Instead of changing the std I would like to add say a noise of 10% of my SNR and then at an specific epoch decrease this noise percentage, how can I do that?